# Is there any downsides to rooting the tab s?

Tags: rooting, 5.1-lollipop, samsung-touchwiz, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-tab-s-10.5

I was recently given this stunning tablet from my company I work for, in the hopes that it could be turned into an offline development platform. I have been looking at alternatives to gain this setup without the requirements of root.. Whilst there are options out there, I always find myself resorting back to the original trail of thought of being manually installing necessary packages to achieve a stunning development platform.

I come here today to ask the following question: *Is there any downsides to rooting the tab-S?*

As lets face it, unlocking the maximum potential for a tablet is a brilliant feeling. The unrestricted usages it provides & the removal of the touchwiz bloatware.

Now, I have done alot of research into the rooting process done on the tablet, it's fairly straight forward and can be acomplished with minimal effort with the use of the auto root tool available, or rooting with the odin tool.

But, the downsides are vaguely listed, most of which revolve around tripping KNOX.. Which in turn makes the use of Samsung pay useless, but on a tablet.. Is it really necessary? On a mobile, I can understand the slight inconvenience it can cause as with the S6 will support Samsung pay and what not.. But regarding the tablet.. What actually are the real reasons to why most people avoid rooting Samsung products?

In the past, I have rooted a selection of Sony mobiles and a few Lenovo tablets, without a problem as they all came with an extremely short list of downsides.. regarding Samsung though.. There are quite a few documented downsides for this process, which are not properly explained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any harm in rooting unless you [brick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_(electronics)) your tab.

Also, if your tablet in under warranty you will void the warranty on rooting the tab.